# How to split a TableCell using Javascript for a Microsoft Word Add-in?

Tags: split, ms-word, office-js, tablecell, word-addins

To my knowledge, there is no way of initializing a non-uniform Word Table (without using HTML or OOXML) using the method `insertTable()`. I have tried to insert a table into the body of a TableCell but it did not deliver promising results.

How would one go about creating a non-uniform Word Table using JavaScript?

(This is my first question, so if anyone has critique on the way I asked this, please let me know so I can improve my future questions!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible: No Word API - not JS or COM - enables *creating* a non-uniform table from scratch via the object model. It's necessary to change a uniform table by splitting/merging cells, which the COM object model does support.

Current versions of the JS APIs do not support either splitting or merging, therefore it's necessary to work over html or ooxml, both of which should work for creating a table. In additiona, ooxml should be able to manipulate an existing table (first read the ooxml, change it, then write it back).

A method to [*merge* table cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=word-js-preview#mergecells-toprow--firstcell--bottomrow--lastcell-) is currently in beta and should be released with the next API requirement set. I see no option for splitting cells, however.